# Diagnosing a dynamic programming vs priority queue situation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, priority-queue

I am trying to determine if the following can be solved using DP or priority queue:

1) I have a set of objects. My goal is to choose enough of them to give me the highest score, while fulfiling a constraint.

2) Characteristic of each object. Each object has a score and a depth associated with it.

3) Constraint: The sum of depths from the eventual set of objects must be <=100

For example

> Index/Score/Depth (numbers below follow accordingly)
>
> 1 70 10
>
> 2 60 30
>
> 3 40 50
>
> 4 40 25
>
> 5 30 35

The possible output from these can be

> Sum of Score/Sum of Depth (numbers below follow accordingly)
>
> 170 90  (i.e. Objects 1,2,3)
>
> 200 100 (i.e. Objects 1,2,4,5) -- the winner
>
> 130 90  (i.e. Objects 2,4,5)
>
> 150 85  (i.e. Objects 1,3,4)
>
> 140 95  (i.e. Objects 1,3,5)

The above shows that the greedy approach won't work, i.e. always taking the highest score or lowest cost. For example taking objects 4,5 (total score 70, total depth 60) is better than taking just object 3 (score 40 cost 50). As a result of this, a straightforward approach will not work, I need to explore my entire search space. So it seems like priority queue won't work, would it? How about DP? Is there a way to apply dynamic programming here?

Comment: Dp is the way to go. Google knapsack problems, there are very efficient implementations out there and most likely you don't have to code it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated problem is a reformulation of the classical Knapsack problem, which is well-known to be solvable by dynamic programming. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming) Wikipedia article for more details. The approach using a priority queue will most likely result in a greedy algorithm, which can be refined to yield a 2-approximation. More precisely, the items can be sorted by efficiency and be taken greedily until the next item does not fit anymore. Then take the better out of this solution and the most profitable item.